# Prove that $(k^k)$ is periodic modulo 3 and find its period.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $(k^k)$ is periodic modulo 3 and find its period. Not sure how to approach this.

Edit: So I know the sequence is 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, ... (plugging in k = 1, 2, 3, ...) so I think the period should be 6 since thats the length of each cycle. I also know a function f(x) is periodic if there exists some minimum n such that f(x + n) = f(x) for all x in the domain of f.

Plugging every 6 term is 0 so f(x + 6) = f(x) mod 3.. is this right?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in some numbers just to get a feel for the problem?

Comment: yes i see that the sequence is 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, ....

Comment: @AE123 you should add that and maybe a bit more description to your question.  Folks like to see what you've tried.

Comment: @AE123: so you know you should be aiming for period $6$. Try showing that plugging in $k=6j+m$ into $k^k$ only depends on the residue class $m$.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ mod prime $\, p\!:\,\ (k+(p\!-\!1)p)^{\large k+(p-1)p}\equiv k^{\large k} k^{\large (p-1)p}  \equiv k^{\large k}\ $ by little Fermat

Answer (score 3):

The sequence has period $6$, i.e., is $(1,1,0,1,2,0,\cdots)$. The periodicity has been proved in the paper [On the last digit and the last non-zero digit of $n^n$ in base $b$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4066), by Grau and Oller-Marcin. In section $3$ they discuss the case $b=3$. The sequence is [A204688 in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A204688).

Comment: +1 for the paper! but overkill for the question at hand. Also while section 2 proves the claim, section 3 is not strictly relevant.

Answer (score 3):

if $k \equiv_3 0$ then $k^k\equiv_3 0$

if $k \equiv_3 1$ then $k^k\equiv_3 1$

if $k \equiv_3 -1$ then $k^k \equiv_3 (-1)^k$